# Iterating and removing elements from ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Tags: java, queue, java.util.concurrent

I have defined a ConcurrentLinkedQueue and looping over it like :

```
 ConcurrentLinkedQueue clq 
 .forEach((carTask -> {
```

Now if I delete carTask from the queue. which is an element 
in the queue while we are doing a forEach will that lead to any issue ?

One alternative I think of is put the elements to be deleted
in a separate List and once the forEach is over simply delete all
the elements in the Queue from the List.
I am not sure if this alternative approach will work perfectly 
Any suggestions or better way to approach this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This specific example won't result in an error, because this implementation of `Queue` allows concurrent modifications.

**But** removing elements from Java collections via the `remove` method, while you're looping over the elements, will often result in a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Instead, it's a good habit to use an `Iterator` and call its `remove` method:

```java
Collection<String> c = new LinkedList<>();
c.add("foo");
c.add("bar");
for(Iterator<String> it = c.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
  String s = it.next();
  if(s.equals("foo")) {
    it.remove();
  }
}
// collection now contains only "bar"
```

In addition to preventing `ConcurrentModificationException`, this is preferable because the time complexity of `remove` for many collections is *linear*. Since this queue is implemeneted as a linked list, the list must be traversed until the element to be removed is located. With an `Iterator`, you've already located the element, and can remove it "in place".

What if you locate the element you want to remove, and it's the last element in the queue? Calling `remove` on that item requires a traversal all the way to the end of the queue *again*. In addition, it requires a call to `equals` for every preceding element. You definitely don't want to put the items to be removed into a list, because you'd have the same negative performance characteristics (along with the allocation of another `List`).

Comment: Really nice, in-depth answer.

Comment: So even if an element is removed. The iterator keeps track of it and the for loop runs fine.      What if during the iterator another thread adds an element to the queue will that get iterated ? or only the elements that were at the start of the iterator will get iterated

Comment: It really depends on the collection that you're using! You should always read the Javadoc for the iterator method to check its guarantees. For `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, the iterator is *weakly consistent*: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly